# window.location.href updates only after the test is done in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, location-href

I use `useNavigate` from `react-router-dom` to handle navigation. I called a `useNavigate` hook at the top level of the functional component like that: `const navigate = useNavigate()`. Inside a `handleClick()` function I use it to navigate to an another page of my website like that: `navigate("/home")`. I tried it and it is working fine, if I click on the button it takes me to homepage (http://localhost/home). However I have problems unit testing this functionality. After simulating a click on that button, the url should change so I wrote the following expectation: `expect(global.window.location.href).toContain('/home');`

The test fails, the window location did not change. However when I tried to console log the window location in the `afterEach()` method, it shows that after the test the `global.window.location.href` equals to `http://localhost/home`. So it is working just can`t verify that in my test....

Why it is only change after the test? What can I do to verify that url inside the test?

Comment: Did you try using `waitFor`?

Comment: Yes, did not work. I also tried using async-await, that solved the problem but VSCODE returned a message " 'await' has no effect on the type of this expression."  I don't really understand how can it help if it should have no effect, so still looking for a better solution.

Comment: Please show entire test code